# GZweb isn't recieving map and robot model from Docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ros, vnc, gazebo-simu

I am trying to run a simulation environment as well as robot model which I didn't build it. So I dowlanded Docker Desktop on my Windows Home 10 and try to run this container called `ayas-gazebo-1`.
In this container. It is supposed to run VNC and GZweb envireonment on the localhost via ports `8081` and `8080` respectively. While VNC environment seem to be workin fine, in GZweb the map isn't loading(only seeing empty grid). As you can see on the screenshots

[VNC Environment on localhost 8081](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8F2Yp.png)

**Note:** also you can observe that Robot Model isn't recieving properly as well as the camera data.

As I mentioned earlier GZweb supposed to load a whole map and Rovers itself.

[GZweb Environment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gUMi.png)

I have been trying to run again and again container ayas-gazebo-1 but it seem to be having same problem. But I am not sure what kind of problem that I am facing.

Also I am attaching the only warning which I get  `ayas-gazebo-1` container's log which I run in Docker Desktop.

```
File "/home/catkin_ws/src/CMakeLists.txt" already exists[WARN  tini (73)] Tini is not running as PID 1 and isn't registered as a child subreaper.
Zombie processes will not be re-parented to Tini, so zombie reaping won't work.
To fix the problem, use the -s option or set the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER to register Tini as a child subreaper, or run Tini as PID 1.
```

**Docker File**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 crudfab/gazebo_docker:v1

# clone gzweb
RUN cd /home \
    && git clone https://gzweb:glpat-oBrz5yqF84131_DeQmoo@ssyz-git.ssb.gov.tr/kangal-otonomi-yarimasi/gzweb.git

# clone source
RUN mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src \
    && cd /home/catkin_ws/src \
    && git clone https://kangal:glpat-URbvXWbozupLiyV8NZvm@ssyz-git.ssb.gov.tr/kangal-otonomi-yarimasi/kangal.git .

COPY ./src /home/catkin_ws/src/examples

RUN cp -r /src/web/dist/* /var/www/html/ \
    && cd /var/www/html/ && chmod -R 777 *


RUN cp -r /src/rootfs/* / \
    && ln -sf /var/www/html/static/websockify var/www/html/static/novnc/utils/websockify && \
    chmod +x /var/www/html/static/websockify/run

WORKDIR /root
ENV HOME=/home/ubuntu \
    SHELL=/bin/bash

COPY ./docker-entrypoint.sh /root/
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "/root/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# setup environment
EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 7681
EXPOSE 11311
EXPOSE 9090
EXPOSE 8001
EXPOSE 80
```

**docker-entrypoint script**

```
#! /bin/bash

ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python

source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source /usr/share/gazebo/setup.sh

mkdir -p /home/catkin_ws/src
cd /home/catkin_ws/src/
catkin_init_workspace
cd /home/catkin_ws/
catkin_make

sh /src/rootfs/startup.sh
```

I have tried to connect the model directly Gazebo environment in Ubuntu but it didn't work. And also Ubuntu environment is too slow in my computer.

**UPDATE**
I have achieved to eliminate other errors the only warning that I am getting is given above. So I made several researches but it didn't work.